# Cron job to run php script

Tags: php, cron

I've got a simple script that sends email if you refresh the page. I need it to run every week. I setup a command in CPanel to run that script

php /home/site/public_html/test/sendmail.php

But it does not work. Hosting support says I setup cron in CP correctly.

I wander if I need any intermediate script to run sendmail.php. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If the script works propperly and the job is called executing the script but it still fails it might be related to privilegs.

Comment: "But it does not work" In what way doesn't it work? What errors are you getting? What are the contents of sendmail.php?

Comment: It does not send email at set interval.

The script works fine if I refresh sendmail.php

Comment: @user3207064 What is the error message?

Comment: @clentfort

Its not privileges. File has proper permissions

Comment: But the cron-user might not be allowed to send emails.

Comment: Talked to host support. Allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you'll need to expand your cron call to `/usr/bin/php /home/site/public_html/test/sendmail.php`, because the system can't find the path to the php executable.

Comment: What do I need to do with /usr/bin/php ?

Comment: @user3207064 prepend it to your scripts path, if it runs without shebang

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a PHP shebang to the script and run it like a normal shell script without `php -f`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
//your code

?>
```

To get the PHP path, use this code: `<?php echo PHP_BINDIR, PHP_EOL; ?>`

Comment: Is there a way to check where path to the php executable is located? Hosting support isnt very helpful.

Comment: use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: In their Help it says - Command to use a specific php.ini file:
php -c /home/username/public_html/php.ini /home/username/public_html/myscript.php

Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: include_path  /usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

that what I see in with phpinfo()

Comment: You might want to figure the basics first before you try putting something up like a mail sending cronjob

Comment: Could you pls tell me where in the page to look for path to the php executable? Under "Configuration PHP Core"? Only sensible information is include_path, but it does not look right - /usr/share/php

Comment: Its /usr/bin/ 

but I tried putting 

#!/usr/bin/php before php script

- does not help

Comment: Talked to host support. This is incorrect - /usr/bin/php php /home/site/public_html/test/sendmail.php

Comment: lol xD shebang is the path to the interpreter, not more: `#!/usr/bin/php`,... not `/usr/bin/php php /home blabla`

Comment: the best thing you could do is download a linux vm and make a crashcourse with the basics

Comment: They have got a field in CPanel to run cron jobs - php /home/site/public_html/test/sendmail.php - this is correct, no /usr/bin/php needed.

Comment: What I cant figure out why then it does not run the PHP srcipt.